# Spring web mvc example, boot, Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder'

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring and largely to Java beyond the language itself...minimal console apps, etc.  I'm trying to get the Spring website example here (https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) to work and I'm trying to stick with the spring boot piece used in the example rather than bailing and creating my own servlet class, etc.  Using Netbeans 8 on OS X Yosemite.

I've been able to resolve a number of issues along the course of this effort but now I'm stuck on this error.  Let me know if more stack would be useful, my pom is below the error.  Any direction is much appreciated:

---Stack trace---

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.modulesToInstall([Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module;)Lorg/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)    at

org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
```

---End Stack Trace excerpt---

---My POM---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-serving-web-content</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <!--version>1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version-->
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <org.springframework.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <thymeleaf.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: You are mixing spring versions and try to work around spring boot, don't. Remove all your `org.springframework` dependencies, those are already included due to the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency. Next remove all properties but the `java.version` property.

Comment: Can I vote a comment as the answer?  Thanks .. Once I reverted to the original example xml and studied the original trace more closely I spotted my very simple oversight/issue which was missing templates directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging from the pom you are mixing at least 3 different spring versions (4.2.0, 4.1.4 and 4.0.5 and probably 4.1.6 from spring boot).

To fix remove all the additional `org.springframework` dependencies, those are already pulled in through the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency.

Your properties also influence a couple of things, remove all of them but the `java.version` property (and if you really  need it leave the thymeleaf property).

These changes lead to a set of libraries that are tested together and will leave you with a single spring version.

If you want to change the spring version, add a property in your `<properties>` element named `<spring.version>` and specify the specific spring version you want to use.

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Just removed the version field and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all folders under your ".m2" folder and run maven build again. I got the issue fixed after few hour of struggle. Seems like some jars are in conflict and its good to get the new ones.
-Hemant

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVED.  Once I reverted to the original example pom and studied the original trace more closely I spotted my very simple oversight/issue which was missing templates directory.

Answer (score 0):

The method is introduced in Version 4.1.5:

Read the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.html#modulesToInstall-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module...-)

> modulesToInstall
>
> public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder modulesToInstall(Module...
>   modules)  Specify one or more modules to be registered with the
>   ObjectMapper.  Modules specified here will be registered after
>   Spring's autodetection of JSR-310 and Joda-Time, or Jackson's finding
>   of modules (see findModulesViaServiceLoader), allowing to eventually
>   override their configuration.   Specify either this or modules, not
>   both.
>   Since: 4.1.5 
>   See Also: Module

So try to change to this spring version.

Comment: He already changed the version, leading to this problem in the first place, mixing 4.2.0, 4.0.5, 4.1.4 and probably another 4.1 version due to the Spring Boot Starter parent as parent pom.

Answer (score 0):

- *Build Tool:* **Gradle**
- *Language:* **Kotlin**

In my case I had the following dependency which threw the exception:

```
api("io.quarkus", "quarkus-spring-web-api", "5.2.SP4")
```

Those that are different from the group `org.springframework` could generate the inconsistency.

---

**Run the app removing all dependencies before the conflict is generated. Then add the dependencies one by one and run the app to check which one is generating the exception.**

To initialize a REST service with Spring it would only be enough with the following in the module using `gradle-6.3` in **gradle-wrapple.properties**

### build.gradle.kts (backend)

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.2.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4-M3"
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
}
```

GL